# I tried rvm install 2.1 and I got this error xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, cucumber

I tried rvm install 2.1

and I got this error:

> xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

This happend while I try to run cucumber tests with ruby.

My ruby version is 2.0 and rvm version is 1.29.3 am not able to upgrade .I have Xcode installed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please run `xcode-select --install` to update it to the last version.

If you still have the issue, please check you xcode-select path with `xcode-select -p` and find the correct path to assign it.

In my case my path is:
`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

so to change the path just run: `sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Answer (score 1):

Install xcode-command-line-tools from following link https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

**Note : You need apple developer account for this method**

or

run following command

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use beta version try  "Xcode-beta.app" in your path:

`sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer`